# CSS: Google Chrome shows reverse :target transition if CSS is loaded eternally

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have the following fairly basic CSS for showing a menu using CSS :target

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  width: 20vw;
  margin-left: -30vw;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

nav:target {
  margin-left: 0vw;
}
```

and some sample HTML:

```
    <body>

        <nav id="menu">
            <a href="#">Close</a>
        </nav>

        <a href="#menu">Show menu</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

While this works, in Google Chrome, when the page loads, the menu slides out.

I've worked out that this only happens if it's an eternal stylesheet. If I use `<style>` tags and embed the CSS on the page it works as expected: The menu is completely invisible until the link is clicked.

It seems that Google Chrome sees the change from no styles applied when the page load to applying the styles in the stylesheet as changing the margin-left property and displays the transition.

Is there any way to achieve the same result with using inline styles or a `<style`> tag? I can apply the `transition` property to `nav:target` instead of `nav` but then the menu is only animated when sliding in, it doesn't slide out and just disappears.

Comment: you are for sure facing [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) due to delay of the CSS loading

Comment: It's definitely similar. If it was just a  flash I wouldn't mind, but it displays the entire animation.

Comment: I think the best solution for this is to consider a page loader that your remove when all the styles and scripts are loaded